# How can I implement pagination in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a project using Symfony2 framework. I am using XAMPP with PHP version 5.5.19. I have table and what I want to do is to put pagination for easy navigation and so on... I am new to symfony that I don't know how to implement it?

Can somebody help me?

Comment: can you please give me reason why to downvote my question? put comment if possible,, thanks :)

Comment: Googling "symfony pagination" comes up with lots of results.

Comment: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle

Comment: @Errorhere a google search would have saved you from loosing reps, oh well that's how they weed out the redundant ones...

Answer (score 6):

Doctrine ORM (included in the Symfony standard edition) has a [builtin paginator](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/pagination.html) available since 2.2.

It has been created to avoid the proliferation of third party paginators (such as mentioned previously PagerFanta and KnpPaginator), is now used by those paginators and is based on their code.

It is very straightforward to use and does not require any external dependency:

```
// Extracted from the Doctrine doc

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Pagination\Paginator;

$dql = "SELECT p, c FROM BlogPost p JOIN p.comments c";
$query = $entityManager->createQuery($dql)
    ->setFirstResult(0)
    ->setMaxResults(100);

$paginator = new Paginator($query, $fetchJoinCollection = true);
```

Answer (score 3):

In my projects I use and recommend the [Pagerfanta](https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta) bundle, maintained, and bug free pagination bundle.

Answer (score 0):

//Twig file code

```
<nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li {% if page_no <= 1 %} class='disabled' {% endif %}>
            <a {% if page_no > 1 %} href='{{ path('pagination', {'page':previous_page}) }}' {% endif %}>Previous</a> 
            </li>

        {% if total_no_of_pages <= 10 %}  
            {% set counter = 1 %}    
            {% for counter in counter..total_no_of_pages %}
                {% if counter == page_no %}
               <li class='active'><a>{{ counter }}</a></li> 
                {% else %}
               <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page':counter}) }}'>{{ counter }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if total_no_of_pages > 10 %}         
        {% if page_no <= 4 %}
            {% for counter in 1..7 %} 
                {% if counter == page_no %}
               <li class='active'><a>{{ counter }}</a></li> 
                {% else %}
               <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page':counter}) }}'>{{ counter }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
            {% endfor %}
            <li><a>...</a></li>
            <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': second_last }) }}'>{{ second_last }}</a></li>
            <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': total_no_of_pages }) }}'>{{ total_no_of_pages }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}

        {% if ( page_no > 4 ) and ( page_no < total_no_of_pages - 4 ) %}
            {% set counterMinus = page_no - adjacents %}
            {% set counterPlus = page_no + adjacents %}
            <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': 1 }) }}'>1</a></li>
            <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': 2 }) }}'>2</a></li>
            <li><a>...</a></li>
            {% for counters in counterMinus..counterPlus %}         
               {% if counters == page_no %}
               <li class='active'><a>{{ counters }}</a></li>    
                {% else %}
               <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': counters }) }}'>{{ counters }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% set counters = counters + 1 %}                  
           {% endfor %}
           <li><a>...</a></li>
           <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': second_last }) }}'>{{ second_last }}</a></li>
           <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': total_no_of_pages }) }}'>{{ total_no_of_pages }}</a></li>      
        {% endif %}

            {% else %}
            <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': 1 }) }}'>1</a></li>
            <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': 2 }) }}'>2</a></li>
            <li><a>...</a></li>

            {% set counterMin = total_no_of_pages - 6 %}
            {% for counterss in counterMin..total_no_of_pages %}
                {% if counterss == page_no %}
               <li class='active'><a>{{ counterss }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
               <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': counterss }) }}'>{{ counterss }}</a></li>
                {% endif %} 
                {% set counterss = counterss + 1 %}              
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        {% if page_no >= total_no_of_pages - 4 %}
            <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': 1 }) }}'>1</a></li>
            <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': 2 }) }}'>2</a></li>
            <li><a>...</a></li>

            {% set lastCount = page_no %}
                {% for lastCount in page_no..total_no_of_pages %}
                {% if lastCount == page_no %}
                <li class='active'><a>{{ lastCount }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
               <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': lastCount }) }}'>{{ lastCount }}</a></li>
               {% endif %}
                {% set lastCount = lastCount + 1 %}
                {% endfor %}
        {% endif%}

        <li {% if page_no >= total_no_of_pages %} class='disabled' {% endif %}>
        <a {% if page_no < total_no_of_pages %} href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': next_page }) }}' {% endif %}>Next</a>
        </li>
        {% if page_no < total_no_of_pages %}
            <li><a href='{{ path('pagination', {'page': total_no_of_pages }) }}'>Last &rsaquo;&rsaquo;</a></li>
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

// controller file

```
public function paginationAction($page)
{
    $commObj = new CommonController();
    $commObj->setContainer($this->container);
    /** session manager creation */
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession(); 
    /* Session Check */
    if(!$session->has('Id'))
    {
      return $this->redirectToRoute('login_login_homepage');   
    }

    if(isset($page) && (!empty($page))){
      $page_no = $page;
    }
    else{
      $page_no = 1;
    }

    $total_records_per_page = 25;
    $offset = ($page_no-1) * $total_records_per_page;
    $previous_page = $page_no - 1;
    $next_page = $page_no + 1;
    $adjacents = "2"; 

    $total_records = sizeof($lists);

    $total_no_of_pages = ceil($total_records / $total_records_per_page);
    $second_last = $total_no_of_pages - 1;

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $repository = $em->getRepository('AppAppBundle:MasterCustomer');
    $select_query       = $repository->createQueryBuilder('QB')
                                     ->select('QB.id,QB.uniqueId,QB.customerName,QB.emailId,QB.mobileNo,QB.customerAddress,QB.customerCity,QB.customerState,QB.customerCountry,QB.status')
                                     ->setFirstResult($offset)
                                     ->setMaxResults($total_records_per_page)
                                     ->where('QB.status!=:sts') 
                                     ->setParameter('sts', 2)
                                     ->orderBy('QB.id', 'DESC')
                                     ->getQuery();
    $list        = $select_query->getArrayResult();

    return $this->render('MasterMasterBundle:Customer:index.html.twig',array('lists' => $list, 'total_no_of_pages' => $total_no_of_pages, 'page_no' => $page_no, 'second_last' => $second_last, 'adjacents' => $adjacents, 'total_records' => $total_records, 'next_page' => $next_page, 'previous_page' => $previous_page, 'total_records_per_page' => $total_records_per_page));
}
```

Comment: Can you also brief out the answer in simple understandable terms?